# How to query all the download item from the system DownloadProvider?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

is there any method to query all the download item from the system downloadprovider,i do this like that,but it need the permission:android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS,and worstly,this permission is in signature level,i can't get this permission,is there other solution to do this.And i just want to develop an app to manager the downloads of the system.thanks a lot!

```
int columnId = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID);
            int columnTitle = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE);
            Log.d(TAG, "query complete!-->" + c.getCount());
            for (int i = 0; c.getColumnName(i) != null; i++)
                Log.d(TAG, c.getColumnName(i));
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                long id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID));
                String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE));
                switch (status) {
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "query one  paused task:" + status + "-" + title + "-" + id);
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                    Log.d(TAG, "query one  pending task:" + status + "-" + title + "-" + id);
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                    Log.d(TAG, "query one  running task:" + status + "-" + title + "-" + id);
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                    Log.d(TAG, "query one  success task:" + status + "-" + title + "-" + id);
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "query one failed task:" + status + "-" + title + "-" + id);
                    // downloadManager.remove(id);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: There's already an app to manage the downloads of the system: Download Manager.

Comment: yes,it is.but i just want know is it possiable to query content://downloads/all_downloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered, the only way to query the `content://downloads/all_downloads` Uri is with the `android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS`, which is a signature level permission. This is intentional and means that it is not possible to read all downloads from a third party app not signed with the system signature.

Comment: Root does not allow you to bypass the Android permissions system - you'd need a custom ROM to change how these APIs are accessed.